# How to use Autodesk.Beeline

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to use Autodesk.Beeline of extended function.

```
<div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var viewerApp;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {                
            var accessToken = '*****';
            var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
            onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
        }

    };
    var documentId = 'urn:***';
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){

        var config = {
            extensions: ['Autodesk.Beeline']
        };

        viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
        viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config);
        viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Error when opening in browser.

```
viewer3D.min.js:32 GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/extensions/Beeline/Beeline.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I do not know how to use Beeline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Sorry.
When deleting the cookie the error ceased to exist.